# Looping and adding to a dataframe in R with a pdf extractor

Tags: r, loops, pdf

I want to read in a pdf via pdf tools, extract some data from it and write it to a csv. I have been able to do this successfully for one pdf, but I have many (440) to do. I'm trying to write a loop that goes through a list I have created that has all my file paths in it. The problem is it overwrites every time. So I think my program is doing what I've asked of it, but I am not asking the correct thing! My code is below:

```
temp <-as.list(list.files(pattern = "*.pdf"))

file_path <- file.path(getwd(),temp)%>%as.list()

data_anz<-as.character()

for (i in 1:length(file_path)){
  data_anz<-pdf_text(file_path[[i]])[2]%>%str_split("\n")%>%.[[1]]%>%str_split_fixed("\\s{2,}", n=4)%>%as.data.frame(i:length(file_path))%>%rename(Commodity =V1, Level = V2, Change = V3, Description = V4)

}
```

What I would like achieve is a data frame that adds to with every iteration, not over writes. So first run, the df = 1 row, 4 cols, the next run 2 rows ect.

I'm lost! But I can get it to work for an individual member of the list and it seems to work through the whole list, but overwrites.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each iteration of the loop is assigning your table to the same variable.  You might want to try something like

```
data_anz<-list()

for (i in 1:length(file_path)){
data_anz[[i]] <- ...
}
data_anz_all <- do.call(data_anz, rbind)
```

which puts each table into its own position in a list, and then row-binds them all together at the end (assuming the columns of the individual frames are compatible).